# SPF record when outgoing mail server is on the same IP as the web server

Tags: smtp, spf

We have been happily using Zoho as an email provider for years, but recently we noticed we we're getting a lot of emails being bounced as "blocked" at our client's ends.
After investigating it seem that a bank of Zoho's outgoing mail servers have been blacklisted as they had been "associated with a spam campaign".

We have contacted our clients and they are liaising with their mail providers to have this reversed, but we know this could take a while. We have been asked, therefore, by our department head, to see if we can setup our own SMTP server for outgoing mail to get back up and running quickly.

I've got this set up and working, save for the SPF record. Emails are getting through currently but flagged as emails are coming from our domain `example.com` rather than a Zoho address.

The SPF record for `example.com` is currently: `v=spf1 include:zoho.eu ~all`

I have tried adding `example.com` as a second include: `v=spf1 include:example.com include:zoho.eu ~all`, but this is creating a recursive loop (`example.com` goes to `example.com` goes to `example.com` etc, etc).

How do I correctly format the SPF record to allow emails sent from our own SMTP server to pass validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If your new [SMTP server uses the same IP address as your web server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.3), then your SPF record can be: `v=spf1 a include:zoho.eu ~all`.
- If your new SMTP server uses its own separate IP address **and** is **both** sending and receiving mail for the domain (hence [it has an `MX` record in the DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.4)), then your SPF record can be: `v=spf1 mx include:zoho.eu ~all`.